# Easiest way to modify a const variable's value

Tags: c++, constants

For my CS class I have a variable `const int m_vin`, throughout my code I am required to edit this value. I was under the impression that `const` variables cannot be edited. How would I go about this?

Edit:
Here are the directions for `m_vin` which is a member variable of an Object named Vehicle:
m_vin, a const int which represent a unique VIN–Vehicle Identification Number (no two vehicles can ever exist with the same m_vin).

In my program I am required to edit `m_vin`;

Comment: You can't.  Period.  If you violate that (and C++ lets you) you have undefined behavior and no longer have correct code, not matter what result you get.

Comment: To edit the value, simply change its initial value. You cannot change it afterward

Comment: If you are "required" to edit a `const` variable, then you need to stop and think about the design of your code. As others have said, you *can* edit the value but the `const` declaration is a red flag that you *shouldn't*. Especially if this `const` variable is from third-party code that you have not compiled.

Comment: I recommend that you check that you have not misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: A const member variable is a curious animal because different object instances can have differing values as it can be initialized upon construction. It's UB because compilers an assume ongoing constness for any given object.  This is a risk since any change by casting for an instance can be ignored by the compiler. To mitigate the risk one can declare the member variable `volatile const` which overrides optimization.  But it's a hack even though it will almost certainly work.

Comment: One could always just replace an object with a copy except the new object is constructed with the desired const member. Another hack, but completely legal. Perhaps the instructor is trying to see how clever the student is?

Comment: I'm curious how one could store a VIN in an `int` since VINs contain alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 3):

**Word of caution:** Modifying the value of such an object, no matter the technique used to do it, is cause for undefined behavior.

You could use:

```
int& ref = const_cast<int&>(m_vin);
ref = <new value>;
```

Don't blame me if your computer blows up.

---

It will be better to change the variable to be a non-`const` one.

```
int m_vin;
```

You should ask your professor/teaching assistant why is the `const` used there if the value of the variable is expected to be modified through out the code. That does not make sense.

Comment: `int& ref = const_cast<int&>(m_vin);
ref = <new value>;` - Ouch. Please don't ever *actually* do that... (meant as a comment to OP).

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

"For my CS class I have a variable const int m_vin, throughout my code I am required to edit this value." - Don't do that. You'll invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Create a copy. Edit the copy. Save the copy back to "wherever".

Don't try to modify `const` variables. Even though the language gives you tools to write code that will do it and that will compile, you will have code that has no well defined behaviour. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Constants (also called literals) are fixed values once declared and initialized. unlike variables whose value can be altered, constants - as the name implies does not change, they remain constant. Constant must have to be initialized at the time of creating it, and new values cannot be assigned later to it.

Consider using a variable if the value will ever change during the program execution.

Comment: Literals are constant, but constant aren't all literals.  Also constants can be variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not do this. Ever.** As stated by R Sahu, you can try `const_cast` to remove const'ness. However, this is not the only guard to fight with. Sometimes (especially if this is a global-scope defined item), memory page that contains the const items could be marked as read-only by OS (I met such a thing on Win XP). So, your attempt to modify const_cast'ed item could end up with Access Violation or similar.

Again: do NOT do this.

Comment: `const_cast` is *only* valid if the object was originally declared "non-const". Otherwise you invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: And UB is about more than just putting you at the whim of the OS. You are at the whim of the compiler first, and that's _much_ harder to reason about. Just don't do it. At all. Ever.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, totally agree this is mad-bad thing. Updated my answer to emphasize that.

Comment: The question involves a member const variable which will always be in ram since each object could be initialized with different values on construction. I suspect that the instructor was pushing the idea of making a constructor that initialized m_vin but hard to say from the question.

Answer (score 0):

> > For my CS class I have a variable `const int m_vin`, throughout my code I am required to edit this value. I was under the impression that const variables cannot be edited. How would I go about this?

As others have pointed out, you can't, at least not directly. And it's not good programming to even try.

> > Here are the directions for m_vin which is a member variable of an Object named Vehicle: m_vin, a const int which represent a unique VIN–Vehicle Identification Number (no two vehicles can ever exist with the same m_vin).

Most likely your instructor is asking you to construct different objects with differing `const int m_vin`. If you do that you don't need to edit them after construction since each object is initialized with a different vin.

> > In my program I am required to edit m_vin;

However, assuming this is sort of a programming challenge, you can change a const member variable by instantiating a new object initialized with the different value. This is best done in a friend function so you can access private variables.

One way to accomplish this is using placement new together with a constructor that has all values needed to initialize the object. First save copies of all the values in the object locally. Use `std::move` for dynamic values. Next, call the destructor on the object. Then use placement new with the argument list needed to reconstruct the object with the new const value.

The following code replaces m_vin with a different value.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>


struct Foo {
    const int m_vin;
    std::string stuff;
    Foo(int m_vin_, std::string stuff_) : m_vin{ m_vin_ }, stuff{ stuff_ } {}
    ~Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1(1, "SomeString");
    int ci = 42  // modify ci
    std::string stuff = foo1.stuff;
    foo1.~Foo();                // in case there is any dynamic objects in Foo
    new(&foo1) Foo(ci, stuff);
    std::string x = foo1.stuff;
}
```

But be warned. You should also use `std::launder` to guarantee the const member will be correctly read. This sort of hack, while legal (I think), harms the readability of the code. People reading the code will, reasonably, assume that const member variables will not change after they are constructed. So don't do it other than to pacify an instructor with a weird request.